# how to put contact no. validation in iphone application

Tags: iphone, validation

I am developing application where i need to get users phone number. Now i want to put validation. It could be textField should not be null and minimum length etc.

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939769/how-to-validate-phone-number-in-objective-c) older SO question for an answer using a regex, but there are so many valid formats for all the different countries that the iPhone is sold in that I think you're best to not even try and just accept any string.